# login failed for user 'domain\localMachineName$'

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, clustering, windows-server

login failed for user 'domain\localMachineName$'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

This appeared on my new SQL Server right after I added it to an existing Windows cluster. It occurs exactly every 5 minutes. Seems a local resource is trying to log in but I can't see what it could possibly be related to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the NETWORK SERVICE account from localMachineName presents itself to SQL Server (and file shares, and web sites, etc).

You need to profile "Login Failed" events (or XE Capture or whatever) to identify the program and/or Windows PID

Comment: Thanks - set up an XEvent session and captured the following: client_app_name SQLServerCEIP

Comment: Just disable the service. This is the telemetry (spyware) element of SQL Server.